# Split an store SQL Objects in separate tables

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

My SQL Query give me error output all time with the following queries. can i set queries while fetching the results?

```
$con = new connection();
$con = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM object");
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($con)) {

mysql_query("INSERT INTO object_meta ('object_id', 'key', 'value') VALUES ('$res[id]', 'parent_id', '$res[parent_id]');") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO object_meta ('object_id', 'key', 'value') VALUES ('$res[id]', 'nice_url', '$res[nice_url]')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO object_meta ('object_id', 'key', 'value') VALUES ('$res[id]', 'startpage', '$res[startpage]')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO object_meta ('object_id', 'key', 'value') VALUES ('$res[id]', 'type', '$res[type]')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO object_meta ('object_id', 'key', 'value') VALUES ('$res[id]', 'title', '$res[title]')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO object_meta ('object_id', 'key', 'value') VALUES ('$res[id]', 'menu_title', '$res[menu_title]')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO object_meta ('object_id', 'key', 'value') VALUES ('$res[id]', 'keywords', '$res[keywords]')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO object_meta ('object_id', 'key', 'value') VALUES ('$res[id]', 'description', '$res[description]')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO object_meta ('object_id', 'key', 'value') VALUES ('$res[id]', 'content', '$res[content]')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO object_meta ('object_id', 'key', 'value') VALUES ('$res[id]', 'date', '$res[date]')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO object_meta ('object_id', 'key', 'value') VALUES ('$res[id]', 'status', '$res[status]')") or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Comment: Obligatory `mysql` is depreciated, use `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping the column names with single quotes which is not corrrect, you may use backticks or no backtics. But make sure to backtick any column name which is a reserved keyword or even the table name.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO object_meta 
(`object_id`, `key`, `value`) 
VALUES ('$res[id]', 'parent_id', '$res[parent_id]');") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: it solves my problem, can you please explayn me why the query works fine in another fault where i only process 1 query?

Comment: You are using a loop to add data. So while doing the loop the table object should have all the columns as you specified in the 2nd set of queries. PS: you need to correct all the queries to use backticks not just the firstone.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is insecure to sql injections. Also you would benefit from switching over to PDO then mysql functions. You create your insert statement once then bind the values to the query. Also this protects you against sql injections without any added code.

```
<?php
$pdo = getpdoconnection();
$data = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM object');

$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO object_meta ('object_id', 'key', 'value') VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
while($res = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $statement->execute(array($res['id'], 'parent_id', $res['parent_id']));
    $statement->execute(array($res['id'], 'nice_url', $res['nice_url']));

    //.....
}
```

Tutorial on PDO

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers